# showing search results more efficiently?

Tags: search, solr

I want to implement the auto-complete feature provided by various e-commerce stores. Functionality is pretty simple, when you type some characters, it start showing relevant suggestions.
I implemented it using solr (django-haystack), using the autocomplete method provided in haystack.query.SearchQuerySet . Basically, i get a list of results sorted by the score. Showing top n results as suggestions.
Solr document contains $product_name, $category_name and other fields. So the results which i generated looks like list of " in ".
Problem arise when i change the category name. If i change the category name, i have to update all the product belong to that particular category to reflect these changes in the auto-complete (update all documents in solr for products of this category).
Another way to do this is by putting just the id of the categories with product in the solr document. In that case, I have do look-up for category name each time, and this is not efficient. 
Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Comment: Sorry but this is not very clear. can you better explain what is your problem with an example maybe?

Comment: Can you not apply the `Category Name` filter to your autosuggest query?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: I have updated the question, feel free to ask if something is not clear.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan: ofcourse, but that is not the issue. problem arises when i change category name in db and not in solr.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing the underlying data, the same has to be propogated to SOLR.

There are different approaches to do this:

1. Update the database, and reindex - Pros: Simple enough, Cons: Indexing time can be large.
2. Update database and Solr in tandem - Pros: Quick updates, almost instantaneous, Cons: Can lead to data inconsistency (if one update fails)
3. Update database, and schedule a delta-import in Solr. This is like a middle ground between the two above.

I would recommend the 3rd approach, but this would require some upfront schema design. Read more about delta import [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command), in context of DataImportHandler.